# Sum Count For Certain Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I am trying to sum counts for the result sets I am getting but can't figure out how. Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT c.clustername AS Clustername, d.district AS LocationName, cty.county AS County, CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT cc.monsterid) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ClusterCount,    d.IRN AS IRN FROM tblCareerCluster cc 
        INNER JOIN tblClusters c ON c.clusterid = cc.clusterid
        LEFT JOIN tblStudentPersonal sp ON sp.monsterid = cc.monsterid
        INNER JOIN tblStudentSchool ss ON ss.monsterid = cc.monsterid
        INNER JOIN tblSchools s ON s.schoolid = ss.schoolid
        INNER JOIN tblSchoolDistricts sd ON sd.schoolid = s.schoolid
        INNER JOIN tblDistricts d ON d.districtid = sd.districtid
        INNER JOIN tblCountySchools cs ON cs.schoolid = s.schoolid
        INNER JOIN tblCounties cty ON cty.countyid = cs.countyid
        INNER JOIN tblRegionUserRegionGroups rurg ON rurg.districtid = d.districtid
        INNER JOIN tblGroups g ON g.groupid = rurg.groupid
        WHERE ss.graduationyear IN (SELECT Items FROM FN_Split(@gradyears, ',')) AND cc.ranking = @maxrank AND sp.optin = 'Yes' AND c.clustername = @clustername AND g.groupname = @groupname
        GROUP BY s.school, cc.monsterid, c.clustername, cty.county, s.IRN, d.IRN, d.district
        ORDER BY LocationName ASC
```

Here is what I get back:

```
Manufacturing Technologies  1   000162  Newark Digital Academy
Manufacturing Technologies  1   048306  Boardman High School
Manufacturing Technologies  1   045278  Carrollton High School
Manufacturing Technologies  1   050237  Chalker High School
Manufacturing Technologies  1   043760  Circleville High School
Manufacturing Technologies  1   043778  Claymont High School
Manufacturing Technologies  1   043778  Claymont High School
```

As you can see I want the Claymont High School to actually say 2 instead of displaying twice per row. How do I do this given the above query and aggregate functionality. I need the rows and their columns from the above query but I need the results tallied properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: remove cc.monsterid from group by, as you have applied aggregate function count on same attribute.

Comment: Could you tell us from which columns you have generated the results table you show? Is 'Manufacturing Technologies' from `c.clustername`? And where do you get 'Claymont High School` from?

Comment: Remove `s.school, cc.monsterid, s.IRN` from your `GROUP BY` ;).

Comment: Manufacturing Technologies is from the clustername and  Claymont High School is the LocationName.

Comment: I removed s.school, cc.monsterid and s.IRN from the group by and it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing much about your tables, the brute force way ;-):

Put the whole `SELECT` into a subquery and then do a `SELECT ... GROUP BY` on it.

**Edit:**

I would like to help you further with your problem, but an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be more than helpful here! 
Also, there are certain inaccuracies in your question:
Your `select` statement should result in an output consisting of 5 columns:

```
SELECT c.clustername                                      AS Clustername,   // Manufacturing Technologies
       d.district                                         AS LocationName,  // Claymont High School
       cty.county                                         AS County,        // ?
       CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT cc.monsterid) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ClusterCount,  // ?
       d.IRN                                              AS IRN            // ?
FROM tblCareerCluster cc  ...
```

So far I can only identify 2 out of your 4 columns you quote as your "result". From which columns do you get the `1` and `043778` ?!?

Comment: Can you be more specific on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hi my suggestion is don't use the count prior, just select which columns you need to fetch data from a group of tables using joins,conditions grouping clause .If it(in the sense select query giving results without any error) working fine then use `select count(*) from (your select query);`